# One test method not detected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

EDIT: I didn't make it clear that one method was dependent on another, thus why I needed the generic. Changed for clarity.

I am attempting to add test methods to some code and for some reason, one method refuses to be detected by Visual Studio 2013. Here is my code.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    ...
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        ....
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
        ...
        Assert.IsNotNull(uploadResult);
        Assert.IsNotNull(uploadResult.AssetId);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void AmIReal()
    {
        Assert.IsNull(null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task<String> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var authClient = new AuthClient();
        var authToken = await authClient.RequestAuthToken(ClientId, ClientSecret, Username, Password);

        Assert.IsNotNull(authToken);
        Assert.IsNotNull(authToken.AccessToken);

        return authToken.AccessToken;
    }
```

When I build this test project, Test1 and AmIReal are detected while GetAccessToken is not. Any ideas why?

Comment: `async Task<string>` what is this for actually?

Comment: Have you cleared your temporary files and rebuilt?

Comment: yea why are you returning `Task<string>`?

Comment: most likely because of generics used in the particular method

Comment: Thank you. I apologize that my methods aren't very clear, but the first method actually depends on the last method for its authtoken. 

@Low Flying Pelican I noticed that if I remove the generic from the last method, it is detected by the test explorer. I'm pretty new to this, why aren't generics allowed in the test explorer?

Comment: @JustinPihony Yes, I tried that and no change.

Comment: FYI you don't have to mark all methods that get used by a test, only methods that you want to *run* as a test... people are asking why a test method would return anything, because (as far as I know) there's nothing that can use the return value when you run it as a test.

Comment: I believe they have never considered as a possibility (if you ask me it's a bug), as @Gus mentioned test methods are not expected to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a returning method won't be accepted as a valid VS test method. Thank you for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`Task<TResult>` inherits from `Task`.

You should be able to return `Task` from that method too, although I'm not sure why you'd return anything from a test method.